# What kind of winter clothing will allow me to feel hits while still keeping me warm in outdoors arena

Tags: equipment, airsoft

Last time I played in winter, I got accused of cheating - likely truthfully but unintentionally. My winter jacket cushioned hits from BBs so much in some cases I didn't feel them at all.

The obvious solution is thinner clothing. Except it was -15C, evening, and thinner clothing would mean COLD. Especially in case you lie in wait in some bushes, sniping, or crawl through thick snow.

What kind of winter clothing (or other solutions?) will be thin enough not to cushion BBs too much while still giving a good cold protection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Always wear special thermal underwear; it is very thin, but keeps you warm even at -30°C.
2. Don't forget about socks; you won't feel foot hits anyway because of boots, so it's ok to wear thick socks.
3. A military-like watch cap is also good.

Source: My own winter-time airsoft experience

[image: Underwear]

[image: Cap]

Answer (score 2):

When I used to airsoft in cold weather instead of a beanie I would wear a facemask. One that looks like you're robbing a bank. I used to wear this same facemask for when I went snowboarding. A lot of times this face mask kept me too warm. So even if you are wearing a thin thermal, this face mask will do the job for protection and warmth. 
[This](https://www.celtek.com/categories/mens/facemasks/) is a snowboard brand that makes some pretty cool face masks. I have one from this company and they keep me warm through any weather, and you have to admit they look pretty sick!